# 302 Error: Laravel 5.4 in SSL AWS ELB Load Balancer

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, laravel-5.3, http-status-code-302

We've deployed a Laravel 5.4 app on AWS (Elastic Beanstalk) with a middleware installed, namely: laravel-ssl-protocol (by resino), which is to force SSL. We've included it on the Kernel.php

```
    protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \Riseno\SSLProtocol\SSLMiddleware::class,               
];
```

It works perfectly on the Homestead/local machine. But it doesn't work on the server (AWS ELB). I attached the actual image or the problem.
[firefox and chrome too many redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmKga.png)

Any idea on how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Behind an ELB you have to configure it to check the `x-forwarded-proto` HTTP header to determine if the connection is secure or not. That middleware you are using says it is only for CloudFlare flexible SSL, so I'm not sure it's going to work in your situation.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that essential info, Mark B. I'll look that up on Amazon documentation. It's a good start to read at.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the fix of my problem and I think I need to share it here. So if somebody with the same problem that I had, this might help them. As I did some research on the web I found this article: [How to Configure Symfony to Work behind a Load Balancer or a Reverse Proxy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/request/load_balancer_reverse_proxy.html) . And did some minor change on the current middleware, laravel-ssl-protocol (by resino) as follows:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->setTrustedProxies([$request->getClientIp()], Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB);

    if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        return redirect()->secure($request->path());
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

And uploaded the updated codebase to AWS and tada! It works. The 302 error was gone for good. The key was "Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB".